# Desktop screenshot in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, screenshot

How can I take a screenshot of the desktop in WPF? Preferably with the mouse cursor showing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without trying to steal the answer, use the code give in the CodeProject article referenced by Johannes to create the GDI bitmap. You can then use the following code to convert it into a BitmapSource for use in WPF:

```
    public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(this System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
    {
        var hBitmap = source.GetHbitmap();

        try
        {
            return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                hBitmap,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        catch (Win32Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            NativeMethods.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        }
    }
```

where the code for NativeMethods.DeleteObject() is:

```
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
```